# How to compare Unicode fullwidth characters with normal characters?

Tags: php, unicode, compare, multibyte

I have code that looks like:

```
<?php
$str1 = 'xxxxxID';
$str2 = 'xxxxxＩＤ';

$bool = ($str1 == $str2);
var_dump( $bool);//==> need return true.
?>
```

Please tell me, how to compare those strings?

Comment: Whatever the “Update” part is meant to mean, please remove it and post a new question if you have a different problem (and you would really need to work on the formulation of the question).

Comment: I have change. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for transliteration. You can use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
<?php
$str1 = 'xxxxxID';
$str2 = 'xxxxxＩＤ';

$str1Translit = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $str1);
$str2Translit = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $str2);

$bool = ($str1Translit == $str2Translit);
var_dump( $bool);//==> need return true.
```

But you should know, that this does not work for every unicode character and may show some odd results.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen();` Will return the number of bytes in a string. Your question is somewhat unclear, however.

Comment: sorry, but my question title has been replace by someone.

Comment: @NolandPhạm Yes. I hope you don't mind. Calling them "2 byte" characters was not clear. Characters like ＡＢＣ are called "[fullwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms#Chart)".

Answer (score -1):

Use mb_convert_encoding() to bring both strings to the same multi-byte encoding (utf-8 or the one of $str2) then you can compare them as usual, using ==

Comment: This won't work. $str1 is ASCII and ASCII is identical to unicode for the first 127 characters. Convertion from unicode to ascii does not work, because ascii does not have a code representation for `ＩＤ`